# Sending Push Notification To All People Who Have Enabled Notifications For My Progressive Web App

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am in the process of developing a new site and have decided to add progressive web app capabilities to the site. I have set it all up correctly and I can send push notifications to devices with whom I know the endpoint via FCM with a cURL command.

My question is how do you send one to all users who have enabled notifications on my site without knowing a list of all users unique endpoints.

Comment: it is not possible without a list of all users unique endpoints

Comment: If that's the case then other than contacting all users of the site to get their end points how am I meant to capture those end points? As without them the Push notification functionality is more or less useless.

Comment: Just like native apps, users have the right to decline to receive notification or not. Sadly, what you are looking for is something sneaky and not allowed.

Comment: I understand that, and I am prompting them to allow notifications as per googles guidelines, what I'm wondering is how do I capture their end point and save it somewhere when they do opt in so that I know who to send notifications too.

Comment: I see, then you need to collect it for each user, if user accepts to receive notification you can get their endpoint in ```.getSubscription()```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) you should be able to get the Firebase token and subscribe that token a topic using the [server side API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) and then you can message the topic.

**NOTE:** This requires the use of the Firebase Web SDK to work. This is not supported with the raw Web Push API.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in using the server side api? Is the a guide or docs somewhere?

Comment: The link in the answer: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances is the best place to learn more, you just add your token where it say IID_Token